# is there a way to nock an array of endpoints?

Tags: node.js, nock

I want to abstract the client API responses from the tests and I'm trying to come up with a helper for that, for example:

```js
class MockedClientApi {
  constructor() {
     this.nock = nock('https://client.domain.com');
  }

  getCountryInfo(country) {
    const endpoint = `/api/info/country/${country}`;
    return this.nock(endpoint).reply(200, responses.getCountryInfo);
  }
  getUserInfo(userId) {
    const endpoint = `/api/info/user/${userId}`;
    return this.nock(endpoint).reply(200, responses.getUserInfo);
  }
}
```

and then in tests, I can write something like:

```js
let mockedRequests;
before('mock calls', () => {
  mockedRequests = [
    global.clientApi.getCountryInfo('GB'),
    global.clientApi.getUserInfo('ABC')
  ];
});
```

and of course, **this is not like the chaining** that nock uses:

```js
mockedRequests = nock('https://client.domain.com')
  .get(`/api/info/country/${country}`)
  .reply(200, responses.getCountryInfo)
  .get(`/api/info/user/${userId}`)
  .reply(200, responses.getUserInfo)
```

as later I do:

```js
describe('when client API is called', () => {
    it('should call all mocked endpoints', () => {
        expect(mockedRequests.pendingMocks()).to.deep.equal([]);
    });
});
```

How can one do chaining from dynamic calls/single calls?

I even tried to come up with ideas that didn't work, like:

```js
  mockedRequests = nock([
    global.clientApi.getCountryInfo('GB'),
    global.clientApi.getUserInfo('ABC')
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are initializing nock multiple times, ending up with multiple/different instances or mutating the original one.

In each class function where you add a mocked request, you should call the instance of nock's "method" function (`get`, `post`, etc.) to add each endpoint you want to mock. Then you could add a function to get the full instance of nock or just create helper functions for each assertion you need, like `getPendingMocks()`.

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const nock = require('nock');

class MockedClientApi {
    constructor() {
        this.mockedApi = nock('https://google.com')
    }

    getCountryInfo(country) {
        const endpoint = `/api/info/country/${country}`;

        return this.mockedApi.get(endpoint).reply(200, responses.getCountryInfo); // return might be unnecessary
    }

    getUserInfo(userId) {
        const endpoint = `/api/info/user/${userId}`;

        return this.mockedApi.get(endpoint).reply(200, responses.getUserInfo);
    }

    getPendingMocks() {
        return this.mockedApi.pendingMocks();
    }
}

describe('make tests', () => {
    let mockedClientApi;
    before('get mock', () => {
        mockedClientApi = new MockedClientApi();

        mockedClientApi.getCountryInfo();
        mockedClientApi.getUserInfo();
    });

    it('should call google', () => {
        expect(mockedClientApi.getPendingMocks()).to.deep.equal([]);
    });
});
```

In the end you should also consider adding an `after` function to clear nock.